# Calculus Partial derivative computation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following systems of equation

$$x^5v^2+2y^3u = 3 \\3yu - xuv^3 = 2$$

I need to show that this system defines v and u implicitly as functions of x and y near the point $(x,y,u,v) = (1,1,1,1)$. Compute all their partial derivatives at $(x,y)=(1,1)$ for local functions $v$ and $u$.
Not sure how to start this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you expand all the variable about $1?$ that is $x = 1 + x1 + \cdots, y = 1 + y1 + \cdots, \cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\vec{x}=\binom{u}{v}$ and $\vec{y} = \binom{x}{y}$. Now let $F(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \binom{x^5v^2+2y^3u-3}{3yu-xuv^3-2}=0$. Take the derivative w.r.t $\vec{y}$ to get

$$F_{\vec{y}}(\vec{x},\vec{y})= \begin{pmatrix}5x^4v^2 & 6y^2u\\-uv^3 &3u\end{pmatrix}$$

Now evaluate in $\vec{x_0}= \binom{1}{1},\vec{y_0} = \binom{1}{1}$. Then

$$F_{\vec{y}}(\vec{x_0},\vec{y_0})= \begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\\-1 &3\end{pmatrix}$$

that has determinant $det F_{\vec{y}}(\vec{x_0},\vec{y_0}) = 21 \neq 0$. What does the [Implicit Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) tell you?

Comment: Thanks! Since the det is non-zero, it is invertible. For the second part do I just take the derivatives of the 2 equations wrt u and v, then evaluate at (1, 1) ?

Comment: That's right! What second part?

Comment: Where it says "Compute all their partial derivatives at (x,y)=(1,1) for local functions v and u". I don't really know what I need to take the derivative of

Comment: Maybe to analyse differentiability given a certain neighbourhood of the point $(1,1)$. We should have to check the question.

Comment: Sorry could you explain by analyse differentiability given a certain neighbourhood of the point (1,1). Thanks

Comment: Sure. Well by the Implicit theorem, once the hypothesis are satisfied we obtain a differentiable function (diffeomorphism) $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined on some neighbourhood $N$ of $\vec{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $F(\vec{x},f(\vec{x})) = 0$, for all $\vec{x} \in N$. That's what I think is "local". But, yes, take the partials and plug $\vec{x_0}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19020/discussion-between-lllll-and-aaron-maroja).